Accept CSV of DTOs in Spring Web REST controller
I need to create a POST endpoint that accepts a CSV file of DTOs.
How do I achieve it?
Spring Web can automatically convert JSONs to my custom objects, so I don't have to accept a string and then parse it myself. Can Spring Web do the same thing for CSVs? Or do I have to actually accept a file and then parse it manually myself (probably using some external library, like Apache Commons Csv)?
// what I want to work but what apparently doesn't
    @PostMapping(path = "/batch", consumes = "text/csv")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> postSocksBatch(List<SocksRequestDto> socksRequestDtos) {
        socksRequestDtos.forEach(socksService::save);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
    }

Attempt 1
I got 415 Unsupported Media Type
    @PostMapping(path = "/batch", consumes = "text/csv")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> postSocksBatch(@RequestBody Object file) {

curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/api/socks/batch' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/csv' \
--data-binary '@/C:/Users/nadch/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/socks.csv'



Attepmt 2
500 Internal Server Error
    @PostMapping(path = "/batch", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> postSocksBatch(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) {

curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/api/socks/batch' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--data-binary '@/C:/Users/nadch/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/socks.csv'


org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Leaving Content-Type blank resulted in 415

The body of your attempt 1 should be of the type "form-data" in postman. In it you should place your .csv file in a key called file or something. You may also want to try using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper medium article by @cowtowncoder for converting csv rows to DTOs.
